# Solving $y'' + 3y' + 2y = x^3$ initial value problem using Green's function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  The textbook is Birhoff and Rota's Ordinary Differential Equations; in the section on second-order linear ODE's, there is the following exercise, which looks like it should be a simple matter of plug and chug:

Solve $y'' + 3y' + 2 = x^3$ for the initial conditions $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$.

I must, however, be misunderstanding how Green's function, er, functions, because I cannot get a reasonable answer.  Here's what I've done:

The characteristic polynomial for our ODE is $\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 2 = (\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 2)$.  So a basis for solutions of our ODE is given by $u = e^{-x}$, $v = e^{-2x}$.  The Wronskian is given by
    \begin{align}
 W(u,v) & = uv' - vu'\\
 & = -2e^{-3x} + e^{-3x}\\
 & = -e^{-3x}.
 \end{align}
    Now let
    \begin{align}
 \phi(x) & = \int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}}{-e^{-3t}}t^3dt\\
 & = -\int_0^xe^{2t}t^3dt\\
 & = -\frac{e^{2x}}{8}(4x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x -3)
 \end{align}
    and
    \begin{align}
 \psi(x) & = -\int_0^x\frac{e^{-2t}}{-e^{-3t}}t^3dt\\
 & = e^x(x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6)
 \end{align}
    Then 
    \begin{align}
 y(x) & = v(x)\phi(x) + u(x)\psi(x)\\
& = -\frac{1}{8}(4x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x -3) + (x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6)\\
 & = \frac{1}{2}x^3 -\frac{9}{4}x^2 + \frac{21}{4}x - \frac{45}{8}
 \end{align}
should be a solution to our initial value problem.  But, though $y'(0) = 0$,  $y(0) = -\frac{45}{8} \neq 0$.

As I say, I can only suppose that I have in some egregious way misunderstood how Green's function is supposed to be used.  Can someone correct my thinking?

Comment: For your $y,$ you left off the $A e^{-x} + B e^{-2x}$ part, for constants $A,B$ to be chosen to fit the initial conditions.

Comment: Perhaps.  Still, by construction both $\phi(0)$ and $\psi(0)$ should be $0$, right?  I guess I must have made a computation error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's too bad that I made such a silly computation error.
We have
    \begin{align}
 \phi(x) & = \int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}}{-e^{-3t}}t^3dt\\
 & = -\int_0^xe^{2t}t^3dt\\
 & = -\frac{1}{8}e^{2x}(4x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x - 3) - \frac{3}{8}\\
 \end{align}
    and
    \begin{align}
 \psi(x) & = -\int_0^x\frac{e^{-2t}}{-e^{-3t}}t^3dt\\
 & = \int_0^xe^tt^3dt\\
 & = e^x(x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6) + 6
 \end{align}
So
\begin{align}
y & = v(x)\phi(x) + u(x)\psi(x)\\
& = -\frac{1}{8}(4x^3 - 6x^2 + 6x - 3) - \frac{3e^{-2x}}{8} + (x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6) + 6e^{-x}\\
& = \frac{x^3}{2} - \frac{9x^2}{4} + \frac{21x}{4} - \frac{45}{8} - \frac{3}{8}e^{-2x} + 6e^{-x}
\end{align} 
which does indeed satisfy the initial conditions.